# Changing website variables in file

Tags: php, arrays, variables, admin

I'm building a CMS that has an admin panel.
I have an array that looks like this:

```
$GLOBALS = array(
    "site_title" => "cms",
    "site_addr" => "localhost",
    "site_logo" => "favicon.png",
);
```

Now as if the user wanted to change the title for example, what is the best way to do it? Should I change the value in the array or should I store that information in the database (But that would then slow the page, right?)?
What would you do?
Thanks

Comment: You'd better store such global variables both in database and in-memory cache. If admin changes the those values, you can update the stored both in db and cache. You should only read them from db if not present in the cache.

Comment: Is your question how do I change the value inside your array? or is it something else?

Comment: Yes, if the best way to handle this is to store the values in an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you store the variables in the database and when the specific user logs into your website, he can extract those values into an array very easily. The best way to INSERT and EXTRACT data from a database would be, in my opinion, using MySQL (PDO).

Regarding your question on slowing the page: databases are designed to execute queries efficiently. Almost all dynamic websites have a bunch of code in the back end being processed every time you enter it so I wouldn't say the speed difference would cause you any problems.

Let me know if that answered your question!

Comment: @T1m1 do you know any php at all? How to use variables is one of the basic parts of coding, including the use of arrays, storing information in them using them in loops, etc, and it would be much better for you to start learning php from the ground up than skip a lot of the fundamental details. It will help you progress faster. Oh and if my answer addressed your initially posted question in a satisfactory way, please accept it (check mark it) so that future users that reard this post understand it worked for you :)

Comment: Yes I do. I just messed 2 answers as the other one talked about saving in cache. I got it the normal array way.